# TypeError: _SchoolProduct__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, react-props

I am new at ReactJs and try to complete a task from the youtube channel.
I created array "products" in "SchoolProduct.js" then using props I passed the value in Product.js.
Now in App.js, I used map function to get data
(Maybe I understand something wrong about props or map function)

Here is SchoolProduct.js:

```
 const products = [
 {
  id: "1",
  name: "pencil",
  price: 1,
  description: "this is pencil"
 },
 {
  id: "2",
  name: "rubber",
  price: 10,
  description: "this is rubber"
 }

]
```

this is my Product.js

```
import React from "react"
function Product(props)
{
 return
 (
    <div>
     <h2>{props.product.name}</h2>
     <p>{props.product.price.toLocaleString("en-US", {style: "currency", 
      currency: "USD"})}
     - {props.product.description}</p>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Product
```

and this my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Product from "./Product"
import productsData from "./SchoolProduct"


 function App(){

  const productsComponents = productsData.map(item => <Product product= 
   {item}/>)

  return (
   <div>
    {productsComponents}
   </div>
 )
}

export default App;
```

The Error is:
TypeError: _SchoolProduct__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.map is not a function

its shows error in App.js line no 8, which is "const productsComponents"

I know I create a silly mistake, but I am trying to improve it

Comment: You need to export the array in SchoolProduct, `export const products = [`

Comment: @Phix now it shows  "Attempted import error: './SchoolProduct' does not contain a default export (imported as 'productsData')."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to export my error in default way,

```
const products = [
 {
  id: "1",
  name: "pencil",
  price: 1,
  description: "this is pencil"
 },
 {
  id: "2",
  name: "rubber",
  price: 10,
  description: "this is rubber"
 }
]
export default products
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Pencil",
        price: 1,
        description: "Perfect for those who can't remember things! 5/5 Highly recommend."
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "Housing",
        price: 0,
        description: "Housing provided for out-of-state students or those who can't commute"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "Computer Rental",
        price: 300,
        description: "Don't have a computer? No problem!"
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        name: "Coffee",
        price: 2,
        description: "Wake up!"
    },
    {
        id: "5",
        name: "Snacks",
        price: 0,
        description: "Free snacks!"
    },
    {
        id: "6",
        name: "Rubber Duckies",
        price: 3.50,
        description: "To help you solve your hardest coding problems."
    },
    {
        id: "7",
        name: "Fidget Spinner",
        price: 21.99,
        description: "Because we like to pretend we're in high school."
    },
    {
        id: "8",
        name: "Sticker Set",
        price: 14.99,
        description: "To prove to other devs you know a lot."
    }
]
```